# What happens if I add a website in compatibility list in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a website and currently works only in IE if I add the URL in compatibility list.

[IE compatibility list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P6LW.jpg)

But as IE is about to phase out I want to switch to Microsoft Edge. But in edge there is nothing like adding in compatibility list. I have tried IE mode in edge but still it does work.

**Note** If I add URL in compatibility list in IE, the website works fine both in IE and edge. So wanted to understand what happens in backend on adding URL in compatibility list.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether you got the answer to your question? If not, I suggest you refer to my answer. If you have further questions, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

While you add the site in a compatibility mode list, the IE browser will display the site in the best suitable IE mode.

When a standards-based webpage is displayed in Compatibility View, the following changes occur:

- Pages are displayed in a mode determined to be appropriate for the site, generally IE7 mode.
- In the user-agent string, the browser identifies itself according to the document mode used to display the site. For example, if the site is displayed in IE7 mode, then the user-agent string contains MSIE 7.0 instead of MSIE 9.0.
- Conditional comments and version vectors recognize the browser as a browser corresponding to the selected document mode. For example, if the site is displayed in IE7 mode, the version vector will be reported as Internet Explorer 7, rather than IE9 mode.

Reference: [Understanding Compatibility View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd567845(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-compatibility-view)

In the MS Edge browser, you could configure the [Enterprise mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode#what-is-enterprise-mode).

You could use [Enterprise Mode Site List Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49974) to create an Enterprise Mode Site List.

Make sure to select/ add the Compat mode(IE mode) in which the site displays properly while you create the site list.

[image]

You need to enable [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list) Group policy and set the address of the Enterprise Mode site list.

After that, you could try to access the site in the IE mode in the MS Edge browser.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I found this answer as I have the same question. But it doesn't answer the question as to whether it is possible to get to the Compatibility View settings if IE isn't available. We're in a position where Enterprise Mode isn't available, and Edge has not correctly detected that the site needs to be in IE7 mode rather than IE11 mode. The only way to get it to use IE7 mode in Edge currently is to add the site in the Compatibility View window, but the only way to that window seems to be from IE (it isn't in the Internet Options control panel).